# Father tries to catch daughter's imaginary friend on camera

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

Mom and dad had moved in to their new house with their two daughters. Their room is upstairs, just off the staircase, with a little closet on the other side. One of the daughters has an imaginary friend there, and it turns out to be a ghost/demon of some sort, and the dad sets up cameras to try and catch sight of this thing. There is a scene of it making a mess in the kitchen during the night. The dad is reviewing the tapes in his studio constantly, and the wife is incredulous that anything is happening. The whole movie just drags on.

Comment: Looks like Paranormal Activity to me. Either part 2 or 3. Cant remember. Although, this seems a very common plot in horror movies. Can be a different movie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like [Paranormal Activity 3 (2011)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1778304/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1).

> In 1988, young sisters Katie and Kristi befriend an invisible entity who resides in their home.

Here is a snapshot of the little girl talking to her "imaginary friend." If I remember correctly, there is a little closet right in-front of where she is standing.

[image]